# Unit testing vue 3 onErrorCapture life cycle hook

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-testing-library

```
import { onErrorCaptured } from "vue";
import { TheLayout } from "@/components";

const snackbar = useSnackbar();

onErrorCaptured((err) => {
  console.error(err);
  snackbar.send(err);
  return false;
});
</script>

<template>
  <the-layout>
    <router-view />
  </the-layout>
</template>
```

I have this SFC code in my App.vue. I want to test the onErrorCaptured behaviour such that it logs the error and sends the error to a the snackbar. So far i have come up with this:

```
  it("should catch errors and logs and send them to snackbar", async () => {
    const consoleErrorSpy = vi.spyOn(console, "error");
    const wrapper = mount(App, {
      global: {
        plugins: [
          styles,
          router,
          i18n,
          createTestingPinia({
            initialState: { snackbarStore: { show: false, message: "" } }
          })
        ]
      }
    });
    const error = new Error("error message");
    wrapper.someMagicMethodToTriggerAnError(error) ????
    await nextTick();
    const snackbar = useSnackbar();
    expect(consoleErrorSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
    expect(snackbar.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
  });
```

What should i do to trigger an error in the component to test the behaviour ?

Comment: You can mock the-layout and make it throw an error

Comment: what if i only have router-view ? can i mock and throw error from router view. is it possible to trigger error without mocking child component?

Comment: It's the same. You are supposed to mock third-party libs in unit tests (and any other unit besides tested one, to put it strictly)

Comment: I still dont understand how to mock and trigger error using the layout, could you give me a reference or code. Im new to vue testing.

Comment: This depends on your setup, which is unclear . The question has vue-testing-library tag, but VTL doesn't have mount(). Generally it would be something like https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/stubs-shallow-mount.html#Stubbing-a-single-child-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As estus-flask suggested the solution is to mock the child component and throw an error from it. Following code shows the approach for the component in question.

```
test("should catch errors and logs and send them to snackbar", async () => {
  const consoleErrorSpy = vi.spyOn(console, "error");
  const error = new Error("error message");
  const errorComponent = {
    template: "<button @click='throwError'/>",
    methods: {
      throwError: () => {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  } as Component;

  const wrapper = mount(App, {
    global: {
      stubs: {
        TheLayout: errorComponent
      },
      plugins: [router, createTestingPinia()]
    }
  });
  await wrapper.get("button").trigger("click");
  expect(consoleErrorSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
  expect(useSnackbar().send).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
  wrapper.unmount();
});
```